# Diffie helman on additive group

Tags: finite-groups

Given the addivite group G, with |G| = n and generator = g, what are the computations and exchanged messages for Diffie-Hellman?

I'm not sure because the group is additive.

Answer (score 0):

"Additive" is just a change of notation; there's no change in how the underlying mathematics works.

Instead of $xy$ where $x,y\in G$ you write $x+y$. Instead of $x^k$ where $x\in G$, $k\in\mathbb Z$ you write $kx$.

It's just a matter of translating the usual DH equations to this alternative notation.

Note that the power law $(g^k)^l=g^{kl}=g^{lk}$ still looks natural in additive notation: $l(kg)=(lk)g=(kl)g$.